# Render Icon in Button Text - Nativescript 6.1.1 and ios 13/Xcode 11

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've had to take over a nativescript project from a former co-worker. We are trying to get the code updated to work properly on ios 13, but I can't figure out why previously working icons in a Button now just render as a '?'. Here is what the code looks like:

```
<FlexboxLayout class="toolbar">
  <Button class="fa-light toolbar-button" (tap)="onNotesTap()" text="Hi"></Button>
  <Button class="fa-light toolbar-button" (tap)="onAddTaskTap()" text="&#xf271;"></Button>
  <Button class="fa-light toolbar-button" (tap)="onDirectionsTap()" text="&#xf5eb;"></Button>
  <Button class="fa-light toolbar-button" [ngClass]="phoneCallEnabled ? '' : 'disabled'" (tap)="onPhoneTap()" text="&#xf095;" [isEnabled]="phoneCallEnabled"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Does anyone have any recommendations or things that I can look at to figure out why this is no longer working? I updated tns-core-modules to the latest version, which fixed RadListView not rendering rows, but now I have this issue. Thanks!

*UPDATE*
So, it has SOMETHING to do with the app.css file not being read properly. I have looked all over the place and in the documentation, but I think that my app.css is set up properly. The reason I think this is that I copied the classes from the app.css to the css for the component, and it shows the images. Any ideas?

*UPDATE2* 
Getting this error in my logs from tns-core-modules/trace/trace.js:174:0. 
Error: Could not load CSS from app.css: TypeError: Expected module identifier to be a string.

Comment: Make sure your font family (postscript) name is correct. Is the issue reproduced on Playground? Or can you share a sample Github project?

Comment: so, like I said, this isn't my project, and it is HUGE with TONS of abstraction (which is honestly super annoying). Anyway, it uses nativescript-angular. This is the error I get regarding my app.css. I don't have anything different than what was there before ios13/xcode 11, so I'm not sure what is going on: Error: Could not load CSS from app.css: TypeError: Expected module identifier to be a string.

Comment: I am also having the same issue on iOS 13.

Comment: I had to add my css to all of the individual files, rather than the app.cs file. It was annoying, but that was the only thing that worked.